# How to respond differently to 404/500 errors with laravel bundles?

Tags: php, api, laravel

I have an application written with the Laravel PHP framework. My main application listens to the 404 and 500 events.

```
Event::listen('404', function()
{
    return Response::error('404');
});

Event::listen('500', function()
{
    return Response::error('500');
});
```

This show my custom error pages to the user. But now, I've also built an API, which lives in a bundle called *api*. This API will be used via Ajax, so I want to handle errors differently. So I added these events to the routes.php of the api bundle:

```
Event::listen('404', function()
{
    return Response::json(array('status' => 'error', 'message' => 'API endpoint not found.'));
});

Event::listen('500', function()
{
    return Response::json(array('status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Internal server error'));
});
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work, it still displays the HTML error page. How can I respond differently to 404/500 errors depending on API or main application?

Thanks!

Comment: Stefan has a decent answer there, one I'd go for if no built in method can't be found. Question: does your api bundle specify that it `handles` the `api` route in `bundles.php`? (Probably a stupid question...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried overriding the main applications listeners from within your bundle? This should remove them as listeners when your bundle is called and leave only your bundles listeners for the events.

You can override events using the `Event::override()` method instead of the listen method.

```
Event::override('404', function()
{
    return Response::json(array('status' => 'error', 'message' => 'API endpoint not found.'));
});
```

Comment: Great! This does the trick. I didn't know about the override method. The documentation doesn't mention it.

Comment: Hi, I was able to get this working for 404 events but not 500: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14276741/custom-error-500-page-not-displaying-using-eventoverride-laravel could you get it working for 500 events also?

Answer (score 1):

In routes.php change the Event listener to:

```
Event::listen('404', function()
{
    if (URI::segment(1) == 'api') {
            return Response::json(array('status' => 'error', 'message' => 'API endpoint not found.'),404);
    }

    return Response::error('404');
});
```

You may need to add something similar in your base controller in the __call catch-all.

Answer (score 0):

Your API could directly return the Response like this:

`return Response::make(json_encode($array), 404);`

Of course you could encapsulate this into a own `$yourApiController->error($data, $code)` method.

Comment: Your proposed method cannot handle unknown API endpoints, e.g. if I request `/api/something_that_not_exists`, it would simply throw the default 404.

Comment: You can listen to unknown endpoints using this method in your api base controller: `public function __call($method, $parameters)
 { 
  $this->error($data, 404);
 }`